# Updating observable in Subscribe in Knockout JS

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I am trying to update the value of one observable when a change happens to another observable using the below code.

```
<input type="text" id="t" name="t" data-bind="value:someValue" />
<br/>
<label data-bind="text: somethingElse"></label>
```

Here is my Model

```
var ViewModel = (function() {
    var vm = {};
    var somethingElse = ko.observable();
    vm.someValue = ko.observable();
    vm.someValue.subscribe(function(v) {
      somethingElse(v);
    });

    return vm;
});

var vm = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

I am expecting when i change the value of someValue i should see the other observable somethingElse getting updated. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here.

[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/WCr8L/385/)

Thanks

Comment: Never mind..was missing the self in the front. so it should be self.somethingElse(v) in case a beginner like me comes looking for answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var ViewModel = (function() {
    this.someValue = ko.observable();
    this.somethingElse = ko.pureComputed(function(){
     return this.someValue();
    }, this);

    return this;
});

var vm = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="t" name="t" data-bind="textInput:someValue" />
<br/>
<label data-bind="text: somethingElse"></label>
```

If you want to update the value of one observable when a change happens to another observable you should use knockout computed (or pureCompuded) observables (see more: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html). I made another change in your HTML code - I changed data-bind type from "value" to "textInput". Unlike the value binding, textInput provides instant updates from the DOM for all types of user input, including autocomplete, drag-and-drop, and clipboard events so you can see your result in somethingElse variable immediately.